# How do you write the valid JS expression [...Array(5).keys()] in TypeScript without error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

One can generate an array populated with increasing integers in JavaScript with the following code:

```js
let myArray = [...Array(5).keys()];
console.log(myArray);   // [0,1,2,3,4]
```

This generates an error in TypeScript ...

*Array(...).keys(...).slice is not a function*

How would I write this as code in TypeScript?

Comment: I've seen this error in TypeScript as well, which is weird because the `...` spread syntax employs `[Symbol.iterator]()` and repeated calls to `.next()`, not `.slice()`

Comment: does the ugly `Array.from({length:5}, (_,i)=>i)` work in typescript?

Comment: or even `Array.from(Array(5).keys())`

Answer (score 1):

Set `"downlevelIteration": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file, so that it compiles down to a more spec-compliant spread operator implementation.

For comparison, here's the output without it enabled:

```
"use strict";
var myArray = Array(5).keys().slice();
console.log(myArray);
```

And here's with, which should produce the result you want:

```
"use strict";
var __read = (this && this.__read) || function (o, n) {
    var m = typeof Symbol === "function" && o[Symbol.iterator];
    if (!m) return o;
    var i = m.call(o), r, ar = [], e;
    try {
        while ((n === void 0 || n-- > 0) && !(r = i.next()).done) ar.push(r.value);
    }
    catch (error) { e = { error: error }; }
    finally {
        try {
            if (r && !r.done && (m = i["return"])) m.call(i);
        }
        finally { if (e) throw e.error; }
    }
    return ar;
};
var __spread = (this && this.__spread) || function () {
    for (var ar = [], i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) ar = ar.concat(__read(arguments[i]));
    return ar;
};
var myArray = __spread(Array(5).keys());
console.log(myArray);
```

It looks lengthy, but eh, that's what you get when you want to support older browsers ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: need to dig into tsconfig.json.